# Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper while connecting to SQL Server with AD password authentication

Tags: sql-server, liquibase, mssql-jdbc

I'm using Liquibase to connect to an Azure SQL Server Managed Instance which has Active Directory Password Authentication enabled. I added `msal4j-1.13.8.jar` to the Liquibase classpath, but I'm consistently getting the following error and stack trace (which isn't very helpful since it doesn't actually indicate why the class can't initialize):

```
liquibase.exception.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://dev-clm--sqlmi-main-s1-us.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net:1433;database=SmallBen;user=*****;password=*****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword; with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Failed to authenticate the user ***** in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:235)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:55)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandRunner.call(CommandRunner.java:24)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$null$2(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:383)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.lambda$execute$3(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:358)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.execute(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:356)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseCommandLine.main(LiquibaseCommandLine.java:93)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.LiquibaseLauncher.main(LiquibaseLauncher.java:107)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://dev-clm--sqlmi-main-s1-us.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net:1433;database=SmallBen;user=*****;password=*****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword; with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Failed to authenticate the user 9f6c8d75-71b0-40e1-b3cd-c4f990e35319 in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:142)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1479)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$2(Main.java:417)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:194)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:193)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:172)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:416)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:234)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:203)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:234)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCliWrapperCommandStep.run(AbstractCliWrapperCommandStep.java:32)
        at liquibase.command.CommandScope.execute(CommandScope.java:212)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://dev-clm--sqlmi-main-s1-us.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net:1433;database=SmallBen;user=*****;password=*****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword; with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Failed to authenticate the user 9f6c8d75-71b0-40e1-b3cd-c4f990e35319 in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:221)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:179)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:144)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:96)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://dev-clm--sqlmi-main-s1-us.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net:1433;database=SmallBen;user=*****;password=*****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword; with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Failed to authenticate the user 9f6c8d75-71b0-40e1-b3cd-c4f990e35319 in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at liquibase.database.ConnectionServiceFactory.create(ConnectionServiceFactory.java:35)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:218)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to jdbc:sqlserver://dev-clm--sqlmi-main-s1-us.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net:1433;database=SmallBen;user=*****;password=*****;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.0152aad5eac5.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword; with driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.  Failed to authenticate the user 9f6c8d75-71b0-40e1-b3cd-c4f990e35319 in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.open(JdbcConnection.java:91)
        at com.datical.liquibase.ext.database.jvm.ProJdbcConnection.open(Unknown Source)
        at liquibase.database.ConnectionServiceFactory.create(ConnectionServiceFactory.java:32)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user 9f6c8d75-71b0-40e1-b3cd-c4f990e35319 in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:277)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:78)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:5647)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5618)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5463)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:311)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:131)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:42)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6490)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:5068)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:93)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:5002)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7685)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4048)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3487)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3077)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2919)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1787)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1229)
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.open(JdbcConnection.java:83)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:275)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:267)
        ... 61 more
```

I tried adding at least 23 other JAR files to the classpath based on research, but nothing helped me get past this issue. No amount of additional logging detail revealed why `com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.JsonHelper` could not be initialized.

Comment: Are all of its dependencies (and their dependencies, and so on...) in the classpath? REF: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j/1.13.8

Comment: Yes, I used that reference first, but then found this article that helped me the most: https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/azure-sql-server-with-azure-active-directory-authentication/49978/2. I actually saw it a while ago but couldn't get Maven to work on my box, so moved on. I tried on another box and got it working, and it showed me the true list of dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

So I found this helpful article a while ago: https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/azure-sql-server-with-azure-active-directory-authentication/49978/2, but I couldn't get Maven to work on my dev box. Eventually I tried another box and got it working, and it did show me the list of dependencies I needed, which are not documented with the MSAL4J repo. Including all of these dependencies in my classpath solved my problem.

Just for reference, this is what `mv dependency:resolve` showed me:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO]    com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:9.7:compile
[INFO]    com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO]    com.nimbusds:content-type:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO]    net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO]    net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO]    com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.9.3:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.1:compile
```